# How to detect if browser will accept xmlhttprequest events by addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

This function inside an object define the event handling for a xmlhttprequest object. As some browsers did not accept the addEventListener method, I did a test so if not, it will define onstatechange:

```
var reqEngatilhar = function(){
    este.concluido = false;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(reqTimeout, este.timeout);
    if(este.Request.hasOwnProperty("onload")){
        este.Request.addEventListener("error", reqErro, true);
        este.Request.addEventListener("progress", reqMon, false);
        este.Request.addEventListener("abort", reqAbort, false);
        este.Request.addEventListener("load", reqFim, false);
        console.log("$Http reqEngatilhar usando eventos...");
    } else {
        este.Request.onreadystatechange = function (e) { reqSwitch(e); };
        console.log("$Http reqEngatilhar usando onreadystatechange...");
    }
}
```

The "este" is "this" outside the function (var este = this;)

The "reqSwitch" will point to the right funcion. The problem is the test este.Request.hasOwnProperty("onload") works only in Safari. How can I make a cross-browser test to detect if the browser will work with addEventListener?

Comment: kill the hasOWnProperty part, those methods are inherited: `if(este.Request.onload!==undefined)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check whether the object has `addEventListener` set to a truthy value. By performing the check this way, you are not dependent on the prototype hierarchy that the browser uses behind the scenes. (As [dandavis pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis), it can be a problem.)

```
if (este.Request.addEventListener) {
    este.Request.addEventListener("error", reqErro, true);
    // etc...
} else {
    este.Request.onreadystatechange = function (e) { reqSwitch(e); };
    console.log("$Http reqEngatilhar usando onreadystatechange...");
}
```

If you are concerned about tools that could muck things and set `addEventListener` to funky values, you could do:

```
if (typeof este.Request.addEventListener === "function") {
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY IT:

```
var util = {
    getAttribute: function (dom, attr) {
        if (dom.getAttribute !== undefined) {
            return dom.getAttribute(attr);
        } else if (dom[attr] !== undefined) {
            return dom[attr];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },
    addEvent: function (obj, evtName, func) {
        //Primero revisar attributos si existe o no.
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(evtName, func, false);

        } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent(evtName, func);
        } else {
            if (this.getAttribute("on" + evtName) !== undefined) {
                obj["on" + evtName] = func;
            } else {
                obj[evtName] = func;
            }

        }

    },
    removeEvent: function (obj, evtName, func) {
        if (obj.removeEventListener) {
            obj.removeEventListener(evtName, func, false);
        } else if (obj.detachEvent) {
            obj.detachEvent(evtName, func);
        } else {
            if (this.getAttribute("on" + evtName) !== undefined) {
                obj["on" + evtName] = null;
            } else {
                obj[evtName] = null;
            }
        }

    },
    getAjaxObject: function () {
        var xhttp = null;
        //XDomainRequest
        if ("XMLHttpRequest" in window) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xhttp;
    }

};

//START CODE HERE.

var xhr = util.getAjaxObject();

var isUpload = (xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload));

if (isUpload) {
    util.addEvent(xhr, "progress", xhrEvt.onProgress());
    util.addEvent(xhr, "loadstart", xhrEvt.onLoadStart);
    util.addEvent(xhr, "abort", xhrEvt.onAbort);
}

util.addEvent(xhr, "readystatechange", xhrEvt.ajaxOnReadyState);

var xhrEvt = {
    onProgress: function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            //Loaded bytes.
            var cLoaded = e.loaded;
        }
    },
    onLoadStart: function () {
    },
    onAbort: function () {
    },
    onReadyState: function () {
        var state = xhr.readyState;
        var httpStatus = xhr.status;

        if (state === 4 && httpStatus === 200) {
            //Completed success.
        }

    }
};

//CONTINUE YOUR CODE HERE.
```

Answer (score -1):

This `addEventListener` polyfill might help you:

https://github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener

Save yourself the trouble of checking browser compatibility and let the polyfill handle that.

Comment: Can you point exactly where [in the polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener/blob/master/EventListener.js) the method `addEventListener` is added to `XMLHttpRequest` objects? I looked and looked and it seems to me that this polyfill is only for objects that are part of the DOM tree.

Answer (score -1):

Try the older way to register events maybe ?

```
    // Pass a function reference — do not add '()' after it, which would call the function!
el.onclick = modifyText;

// Using a function expression
element.onclick = function() {
  // ... function logic ...
};
```

Check out [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners) to know more.